# Isekai manga where mc has a system and skills

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is black and white. Has a male main character with a system and skills that level up as he does. He has a system that starts out robotic in nature but as he levels and gains experience the system watches and learns through his point of view. When he hits a certain level his system "evolves" with his old system glitching out of existence and leaving him with a sadness that is only eased with his last system telling him that the new system is a part of her and him.

Comment: *"Isekai manga where mc has a system and skills"* - This is about half of all isekai mangas.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpEkaDf0SXI perhaps? This is the only mention I've found of the title, though.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - That's **I Kill to be God: Beyond the Human Barrier** - *"Amid a foreign dimension invasion, all life on Earth mutated. Humans were compelled to retreat, leaving behind vast lands now known as the Wasteland, inhabited by these foreign creatures. Jiang Han, a low-talent awakener, finds himself unexpectedly bound to an MMO system. He gains XP and levels up by slaying monsters. “Congratulations, host, for killing the Lord-level monster Steel-mane boar king. Gained 58965 EXP.” “Congratulations, host, for using the talent enhancement card. The current talent level increased by one.*"

Comment: No that is a manhwa the series is a manga (Japanese manga not Korean manhwa) and it is black and white not full color (and why I left it vague is for the very reason that nobody knew what it was on the last post I made) but I appreciate the guess though

Answer (score 0):

It might be Kami no Techigai de Shindara Zumi de Isekai ni Hourikomare Mashita

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?

Comment: Myanimelist entry at https://myanimelist.net/manga/130204/Kami_no_Techigai_de_Shindara_Cheat_Gun_Tsumi_de_Isekai_ni_Hourikomaremashita doesn't seem to provide such details. But I have not read the manga.